# Finding a path of given length N in a DAG

Tags: algorithm, path, graph-theory, graph-algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

You are given a **directed acyclic graph**, that is a rooted tree(so all edges are directed downwards and no two paths going from the root can intersect). You know the length of each edge in the graph. I'm looking for an algorithm to check if there exists some **path of length N** in linear time.

I'm thinking about converting the graph into a topological order and then just going through each vertex while keeping track of all paths that start in given vertex. I'm not sure if that is the right solution. Can I get any help on how to do this better?

Comment: What are the constraints on `N`, the number of nodes and the length of each edge?

Comment: N is the sum of lengths of the edges contained in the path.

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I asked. What is the range of possible values for `N`, the number of nodes in the graph and the length of each edge in the graph?

Comment: Suppose that all edges have positive lengths and N is positive and is smaller than the length of a longest directed path in the graph.

Comment: And what is the maximum number of nodes your graph can have?

Comment: How is your graph represented? (Obviously not an adjacency matrix, since then you would certainly need at least quadratic time.)

Comment: Well the representation is also a part of the question :D I feel like for a DAG the topological order could be a way to go. Maybe even a hash set where each hash represents a child of a given node.

Comment: And it's not specified how many nodes the graph has, only that it is finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your tree is directed and cannot have up-then-down paths, the following is a linear solution in the number of nodes of the tree.

I feel like this is easier to explain if we first consider a simpler problem: given an array `a`, find if there is a subarray that sums to `N`.

We would use prefix sums for this:

```
s[0] = a[0]
s[i > 0] = s[i - 1] + a[i]
```

Then the idea is to check, for each `0 <= i < a.len`, if `s[j < i]` contains a value `p` such that `s[i] - p == N`. Rewriting this, we get, `p == s[i] - N`.

A naive implementation would be:

```
s[0] = a[0]
if a[0] == N:
    found it!
for i = 1 to a.len:
    s[i] = s[i-1] + a[i]
    for j = 0 to i:
        if s[j] == s[i] - N:
            found it!
```

However, we can replace the nested for loop with a dictionary for an `O(a.len log a.len) / O(a.len)` solution.

We need to implement the same solution for the tree, building that dictionary during a depth first search, but taking care to remove elements from it when returning from the recursive calls:

```
DFS(node, sums_dict, current_sum):

    if current_sum - N in sums_dict:
        found it!
    else:
        sums_dict.add(current_sum)
        for c in node.children: 
            DFS(c, sums_dict, current_sum + c.edge_len)
        sums_dict.remove(current_sum)
```

Initial call: `DFS(root, <empty>, 0)`.

Time complexity: `O(T * D)`, where `T` is the number of nodes in the tree and `D` is the complexity of our dictionary: `O(log T)` or `O(1)`.

Comment: Hmm, yea that was the solution that I thought about too. The problem that I had with the DFS approach is that you visit each node twice while backtracking. I fell like since it is an directed tree so all of the edges go from the root only downwards, there has to be a way to visit each node and edge only once therefore getting the complexity of O(T+E) where T is the number of nodes and E is the number of edges.

Comment: But thank you for this very detailed solution, I'll go with this if I won't be able to find what I'm looking for :)

Comment: I doubt it can be done faster as stated. Unless you add restrictions such as: it's a BST, or it's a downwards only path (no up then down paths: `/\\`).

Comment: Well, up and down paths will render some nodes unreachable, since there are not any cycles. I guess I should have mentioned that. But all edges are directed downwards. And also no paths that start in a root can intersect. I oversimplified the original task by only saying that it is a rooted tree, I see now that it wasn't clear enough what I mean by that :D

Comment: Ok, well that makes things easier :) I should have read more carefully that you said it's directed, so can't have up then down paths. Just ignore the second case I wrote in the answer and you're done in `O(T * D)`.

Comment: Oh now I see it, it is actually linear like this. I was overcomplicating this trying to come with a solution that would dynamically be caching all possible paths from each node and counting. This is way easier, thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! If you like the answer, please consider accepting and upvoting it.